# OpenCV2.3.1, basic program, in QtCreator not working

Tags: opencv

Following the very first OpenCV program given in the OpenCV2 - Computer Vision Application Programming book, and following all steps to set up QtCreator, I still can't get the program to run as expected.

I am using Qt Creator 2.4.1 (based on Qt 4.7.4 (64 bit)), and this is what my .pro file looks like -

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = myQtConsoleProject
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib \
-lopencv_core \
-lopencv_highgui \
-lopencv_imgproc \
-lopencv_features2d \
-lopencv_calib3d
```

Here is the program:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // read an image
    //cv::Mat image = cv::imread("lena.jpg", 1);
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("/home/icarus/Pictures/lena.jpg");
    cv::Mat image(img);
    cvReleaseImage(&img);

    // create image window named "My Image"
    cv::namedWindow("My Image");

    // show image on window
    cv::imshow("My Image", image);

    // wait key for 5000ms
    cv::waitKey(50000);


    return 1;
}
```

The code apparently has no compilation errors or warnings, but on clicking the "Run" button on QtCreator (which should build and then execute this application), all I get is a terminal window with the title "qtcreator_process_stub", which shows:

> Press  to close this window...

However what I expect is a OpenCV GUI window showing lena.jpg with the title "My Image". Any clues on what might be going on ?

On QtCreator application console, this is what I see:

```
Starting /home/icarus/Work/MachineVision/Projects/myQtConsoleProject-build-desktop-Desktop_Qt_4_8_0_for_GCC__Qt_SDK__Release/myQtConsoleProject...
/home/icarus/Work/MachineVision/Projects/myQtConsoleProject-build-desktop-Desktop_Qt_4_8_0_for_GCC__Qt_SDK__Release/myQtConsoleProject exited with code 0
```

Note that I know for sure that I have a good built-from-source OpenCV-2.3.1 installation, which is tested by running some of the sample apps. Also, I am pretty sure that my paths, as specified in the .pro file, are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the right cause for the behaviour you see, but I do think that it is an issue.

According to the documentation http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html
(or just search for it, in case the link goes dead)

The constructor you used for Mat is defined as follows:

```
Mat::Mat(const IplImage* img, bool copyData=false)
```

You used:

```
cv::Mat image(img);
cvReleaseImage(&img);
```

Since copyData is false by default, and you did not pass a 'true' variable, it means that Mat is referring to the same memory as IplImage.

Now you have released the memory of IplImage (img) before displaying it. That is an issue.

Try adding

```
if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
{
    cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
    return -1;
}
```

before you display the image to verify this.